# The total number of prime factors of this expression

Tags: discrete-mathematics

The total number of prime factors of this number:
$2^{22}$ x $7^5$ x $11^2$

Should be only 3, which are 2, 7 and 11 itself. However the answer states that there are total $(22+5+2) = 29$ prime factors. What? How?

Comment: You answer to the question "what is the total number of distinct prime factors of this expression?". They answer to the question in the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are asked

> How many prime factors does the number $n$ have?

this doesn't mean

> How many factors / divisors does $n$ have that are prime?

which is what you answered, but rather

> If you write $n$ as a product of primes, how many factors do you get?

In this case we get twenty-two 2's, five 7s and two 11s for a total of 29.